# Grouping views in settings android

Tags: android, grouping, material-design

I'm building a app and I want to create grouping of my settings for the app, like you can do with a Preference Screen. I'm using the Support Design Library to be able to use Floating Labels and so on.

I've been searching like crazy but can't seem to find any answer...

Hope someone here knows how to do this and can help, and hope you understand what I want to do, despite my rusty english :)

I would like the below image but not using the "PreferenceActivity".

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: can you explain it by any design or something image where you saw this grouping view??@feeloor

Comment: Yes, sorry for the poor description. Here is an image: https://itaffinity.files.wordpress.com/2015/06/04-nusic-abc-prefs.png I would like it like that but not using the "PreferenceActivity".

Comment: Um, why aren't you using a `PreferenceScreen`, if you want something that looks like a `PreferenceScreen`? Bear in mind you do not need `PreferenceActivity` to use a `PreferenceScreen`, as you can use `PreferenceFragment`. Beyond that, you might wish to explain **specifically** what it is that you do not know how to do. The "grouping" is merely a `TextView`, AFAICT.

Comment: The thing is, when I use the PreferenceScreen I get the "warning" that it is depricated... So I thought it was good practice to use some "newer" way... Also I want to use the TextInputLayout that comes with the Support Design Library.

Comment: Is it possible to add the Support Design Library to preferences? Because when I try it says it cant be cast to android.preference... I want to use the TextInputLayout so I get the floating labels :)